# Can exceptions sneak between restore and mask?

Tags: exception, haskell, asynchronous, resources

Suppose I have some code written like so:

```
import Control.Exception (bracketOnError, finally, mask)
import Client (acquireB, releaseB, doStuff) -- theoretical
import MyStuff (preliminary, doMoreStuff) -- theoretical

clientAction = bracketOnError acquireB releaseB $ \b ->
  doStuff b
  return (b, releaseB b)

myAction = mask $ \restore ->
  a <- preliminary
  (thing, releaseThing) <- restore clientAction
  doMoreStuff a thing `finally` releaseThing
```

I have to do some `preliminary` stuff, my client acquires `b` and then has to `doStuff` with `b`, and then I have to `doMoreStuff` with `b`. And `b` needs to be released, even if an asynchronous exception occurs. But I don't know how to release `b`, so my client tells me how. Written this way, we are both prepared to release `b` if an exception happens during "our" code.

My question is this: Is it ever possible for an async exception to cause `releaseB` not to be performed? Specifically, is there a gap between "my code" and "my client's code" where an async exception can squeeze in? Let me inline `clientAction` and `bracketOnException` to explain.

```
myAction = mask $ \restore -> do
  a <- preliminary
  (thing, releaseThing) <- restore $ mask $ \restore2 -> do
    b <- acquireB
    restore2 (doStuff b >> return (b, releaseB b))
      `onException` releaseB b
  doMoreStuff a thing `finally` releaseThing
```

The concern is this: is there a moment right here

```
... restore $ mask ...
```

Right when the client's `mask` is lifted, but before the end of my `restore` surrounding it, where an exception could sneak through?

Comment: To resolve your issue, you could pass restore as an argument, instead of restoring yourself around the client code.

Comment: @Peaker Dan and I were discussing various APIs to use for WAI. We *did* discuss passing in `restore` as an argument, but I was worried that it would be too easy for users to forget to unmask async exceptions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in GHC, when the unmask occurs we eagerly check for blocked exceptions and raise them.